# Add casual material such as screenshot fast to Final Cut Pro video? How? From Desktop?

Tags: aperture, final-cut-pro

I am able to add pictures from iPhone and Aperture to Final Cut Pro and I would like to fast add screenshots. I tried to do this from Desktop and no such option.

[image]

**How can I fast add casual material such as screenshots to a FCP video?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag the image in from Finder (including Desktop and Dock) to the timeline:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was so super easy! I earlier imported to Aperture to get them and this requires only dragging, super cool :) Thanks again!